# How to convert base64 byte to string byte without extra slashes and b''

Tags: python, base64

I want to convert this base64 string to a byte string like this:

base64:

```
XHhjXHg0OFx4ODNceGU0XHgwXHhlOFx4Y2NceDAwXHgwMFx4MDBceDQxXA==
```

string byte:

```
\xc\x48\x83\xe4\x0\xe8\xcc\x00\x00\x00\x41\
```

I made this code:

```
bstring = "XHhjXHg0OFx4ODNceGU0XHgwXHhlOFx4Y2NceDAwXHgwMFx4MDBceDQxXHg1MVx4NDFceDUwXHg1Mlx4NTFceDU2XHg0OFx4MzFceGQyXHg2NVx4NDhQxXHhhXHgwXHgyXHgwXHgzMFx4XHhkNVx4NTdceDU5XHg0MVx4YVx4NzVceDZlXHg0ZFx4NjFceFx4ZDVceDQ5XHhceGNlXHhlOVx4M2NceFx4XHhceDQ4X"
decoded = base64.b64decode(bstring)
buffery = ''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(b) for b in decoded)
print(buffery)

#with open('shell', 'r') as f:


#null

def main():

    #null
    #ct.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ct.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0)
    #null

    sleep(1)

    #null

    void_type = ct.c_void_p
    len_buffery = ct.c_int(len(buffery))
```

And this is the output:

```
b'\\xc\\x48\\x83\\xe4\\x0\\xe8\\xcc\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x41\\'
```

So this is the problem. I don't wanna double slash and b'' so how can I convert it like this (I need byte): `\xc\x48\x83\xe4\x0\xe8\xcc\x00\x00\x00\x41\`?

Comment: `b'\\xc\\x48\\x83\\xe4\\x0\\xe8\\xcc\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x41\\'` is just the way `\xc\x48\x83\xe4\x0\xe8\xcc\x00\x00\x00\x41\` is displayed when inside a bytestring. Each pair of slashes only represents a single slash, as that is the escape sequence. All the underlying data is the same.

Comment: @MichaelM. If you executing shellcode, its not same thing

Comment: @theflyingasshole What do you mean? They represent the same data, Python's just displaying it differently.

Comment: It seems like this question might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: cant reproduce, getting  binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael M. said, the output you are getting is Python's representation of the byte string. If you want to see it exactly like you want it, try this:

```
bstring = "XHhjXHg0OFx4ODNceGU0XHgwXHhlOFx4Y2NceDAwXHgwMFx4MDBceDQxXA=="
decoded = base64.b64decode(bstring)

hex_string = ''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(b) for b in decoded)
print(hex_string) # outputs: \x5c\x78\x63\x5c\x78\x34\x38\x5c\...
```

Comment: but its not byte i edited my code you will uderstand me

Comment: I need make it as bytes object not str im getting this error:     sicmik = (ct.c_char * len(buffery)).from_buffer_copy(buffery)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Well then, for gosh sakes, do `b''.join(b'\\x...` to make it a bytes string.  This is not hard.